# How to run an activity once when you first open Android app

Tags: java, android

I have a music streaming app that has free features as well as paid features. The main activity offers the option to login/subscribe or try free. If user selects "Login/subscribe" then they are taken to the login screen where they can login or create an accout. However, if user selects "Try free" then they are taken to the library screen with limited functions. The way it is right now, if they select "Try free", then every time they open the app it asks them again to Login or Try free.

I want to change that so that, once they select "Try free" option they never see the options again but are taken to the library screen with limited functions.

So, I set HomeActivity, which is the activity I want to use every time after the first launch, as the launch option. That works great.

Then I added the following code to onCreate in HomeActivity.java

The idea is that on first launch it will lauch MainActivity, then set the Boolean isFirstRun to false, and never launch MainActivity again.

But, it's not working. Seems like it is setting isFirstRun back to true every time. How do I fix that?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    if (isFirstRun) {
        //show start activity

        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        Toast.makeText(this, "First Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }


    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
```

Comment: BTW, I did not write this code. I had the app done by someone else, but they've been difficult to deal with so I'm trying my hand at fixing some bugs.

Comment: Try using fragment in your MainActivity, then choose the fragment you want and load it

Comment: I edited my question as I found a solution that should work, but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. It was my own fault.

Though I had specified a different activity to launch under Run>Edit Configuration, I had not set an intent filter in my mainifest file for the HomeActivity.....

Live and learn I guess